# Connecting to MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

Can anyone help me out with this error here? Is it a syntax error?

Username:root
No password

**Code:**

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection conn = null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/main"
            + "user=root&password=");
```

**Output:**

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mainuser=root&password='
```

Comment: Can you connect from the command line using the `mysql` tool?

Comment: Try `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/main", "root", "");`

Comment: Shouldn't there be `?` after `main` and before `user=`?

Comment: @Pshemo Hi what is the "?" for? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: If you are creating URL to resource and you want to pass some parameters using GET you need to use `protocol://address/to/resource?param1=value1&param2=value2` and so on. I assume that same rule is used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `?` before `user`.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/main?" +
                               "user=root&password=");
```

It's worth reading [Oracle Tutorial - Establishing a Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

---

You can try with `Properties` as well. Look at [DriverManager.getConnection(String,Properties)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties%29) constructor and there are more try with any one.

```
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("user", "root");
connectionProps.put("password", "");

String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/main";

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connectionProps);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method signature instead

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url, String user, String password) throws SQLException
```

In your case it will be

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/main", "root", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong 
Try this

> (Jdbc:mysql://localhost/main,root,passwd)